# mysql master AND slave two server replication

Tags: mysql, replication, lamp, master-slave

Is it possible for a mysql server to be both a master and a slave at the same time? I want server1 to be the master for db1 (with server2 operating as slave for db1) Additionally I would like server1 to be a slave for db2 (with server2 acting as the master for db2). Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by having each mysql server be a slave of the other. 
You need to take extra care to coordinate who writes what.
In your case this shouldn't be a problem as each mysql instance is exclusively responsible for its database.

Check for "master-master" replication, e.g.:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication